# CSS Centering of Image

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, image, center, centering

I'm working in visual studio with the following code,
however, the URL images refuse to center in the columns like the h2 tags did.
ive tried multiple options such as

```
  background-image: url('http://i59.tinypic.com/314uzyb.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

also

```
  background: url('http://i59.tinypic.com/314uzyb.jpg') center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

here is what it currently looks like. As you can see, my h2 tags are centered with the columns. however, the images are still left bound.
[image: would like to center both pills to center of their columns]
here is the full section of code:

```
      <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Version 1.0</h2>

    @*EDIT________________BUTTON1 THAT TAKES USER TO A CREATE PAGE FOR SPECIFIC SONG TYPE(KEY)*@
    <style type="text/css">
        .urlImg1 {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            display: block;
            background-image: url('http://s28.postimg.org/3jrpa5hvx/BUTTON1_A.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

            .urlImg1:hover {
                background-image: url('http://s13.postimg.org/brbfy86xz/BUTTON1_B.jpg');
            }
    </style>
    <a href="http://www.corelangs.com" class="urlImg1" title="Corelangs link"></a>
    @*END BUTTON#1_____________________________________*@
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Version 2.0</h2>

    @*EDIT________________BUTTON2 THAT TAKES USER TO A CREATE PAGE FOR SPECIFIC SONG TYPE(KEY)*@
    <style type="text/css">
        .urlImg2 {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            display: block;
            background-image: url('http://i59.tinypic.com/314uzyb.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

            .urlImg2:hover {
                background-image: url('http://i60.tinypic.com/rmp4pv.jpg');
            }
    </style>
    <a href="http://www.corelangs.com" class="urlImg2" title="Corelangs link"></a>
    @*END BUTTON#2_____________________________________*@
</div>
```

Comment: A Demo would be useful because  your code is **very** hard to interpret.

Comment: Yes, a jsfiddle that reproduce the problem would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're trying to center the image while the element is as wide as the image. In other words, the image is centered it's just that the  element is as wide as the image which makes it appear not centered.

**Examples**

http://jsfiddle.net/ey0upzw1/

```
width: 500px; /* Equal to col width */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ey0upzw1/1/

```
width: 200px; /* Not equal to col width */
```

**Solutions**

Settings the image to `margin: auto`.

Adding `text-align: center` to `col-4` instead of only on the `h2`, you also have to set the image to `inline-block` instead of `block`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to center the link.

Since it has a defined width, you can do that with `margin:auto`.

```css
.urlImg1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('http://s28.postimg.org/3jrpa5hvx/BUTTON1_A.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: auto;
}
.urlImg1:hover {
  background-image: url('http://s13.postimg.org/brbfy86xz/BUTTON1_B.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Version 1.0</h2>
  <a href="http://www.corelangs.com" class="urlImg1" title="Corelangs link"></a>
</div>
```